# Managed server is not able to start if added to an existing cluster

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c

On trying to add a newly created managed server to an already existing cluster, I'm unable to start this managed server. It's throwing the following error.

**Log:**

Failed to find the log query mbean. JMX call: validateTargets for the Secure target [/Domain_adf_domain/adf_domain, weblogic_domain] 
Target List [[/Domain_adf_domain/adf_domain/ms-3,weblogic_j2eeserver][com.bea:Name=ms-3,Type=Server], [/Domain_adf_domain/adf_domain/ms-3/state-management-provider-memory-rar,j2ee_application]
[com.bea:Name=state-management-provider-memory-rar,Location=ms-3,Type=AppDeployment], [/Domain_adf_domain/adf_domain/ms-3/coherence-transaction-rar,j2ee_application]
[com.bea:Name=coherence-transaction-rar,Location=ms-3,Type=AppDeployment], [/Domain_adf_domain/adf_domain/ms-3/DMS Application(12.2.1.0.0),j2ee_application][com.bea:Name=DMS Application#12.2.1.0.0,Location=ms-3,Type=AppDeployment]],
 Log Query MBean [oracle.logging:type=LogQuery,name=ms-3,Location=ms-3] 
Exception Message:Unable to contact MBeanServer for oracle.logging:type=LogQuery,name=ms-3,Location=ms-3

Already there exists a managed server in this cluster, in which our application is working fine. Then, I tried to add the new managed server as standalone and deployed our ADF application in it and this works like a charm. Can anyone please tell me why it's not working if I add it to the cluster? Am I missing out any configuration?

Weblogic version : 12c
OS : Windows

Provided unicast clustering and both managed servers are in same machine..

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get host address from the command: `$ hostname -i`
Then, at weblogic console, add an argument at `server start` tab of managed server:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<the host address that you found>'
```